# Row grouping is possible in React-Data-Table-Component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-data-grid, react-data-table-component

> Hi everyone, I need to group the data by name. It's possible to group rows in the react-data-table component.

Like This:

[image: Grouping]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code providing service, instead you can do your research, come up with a solution to your problem with some code and if you have issues or errors, you may then seek for help here. You may have a look and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

no it's not possible in react data table component as of now

Comment: https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/issues/367

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).